A question from Advanced problems in mathematics for JEE main and advanced aka black book from the topic of functions
The question is as follows:
Find the number of real ordered pair(s) (x,y) for which :
$$
16^{x^2+y} + 16^{x+y^2} = 1
$$
(a) 0
(b) 1
(c) 2
(d) 3
the answer is option b
my approach to this question is as follows:
$$
16^{x+y}(16^x+16^y) = 1
$$
$$
(16^x+16^y) = \frac{1}{16^{x+y}}
$$
after this I didn't find further approach

How did you obtain $16^{x+y}(16^x+16^y) = 1$? You either made a mistake or there is a nontrivial mathematical step missing, because ${16}^{x+y}({16}^x+{16}^y) = {16}^{2x+y} + {16}^{x+2y} \neq {16}^{x^2 + y} + {16}^{x + y^2}.$

Perfect Solution , @ameg , you should Post that answer !!

OP has a wrong factorization here , @DaveL.Renfro , mixing up $2A$ with $A^2$ in the Power terms.

@ameg Thank you

@ameg actually can you tell me why $ \frac{16^{x^2+y} +16^{y^2+x}}{2} = 2^{-1} $

That is the original equation, divided by $2$.

@ameg ok got it

By AM-GM, LHS $\ge 2 \sqrt{16^{x^2+y^2+x+y}}$
Now $x^2+y^2+x+y=\left(x+\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^2+\left(y+\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^2 -\dfrac{1}{2} \ge -\dfrac{1}{2}$
Hence $2 \sqrt{16^{x^2+y^2+x+y}} \ge 1$ with equality when $x=y=-\dfrac{1}{2}$ which also satisfies $x^2+y=y^2+x$
Thus the unique solution is $x=y=-\dfrac{1}{2}$
